# How to link a static library in Visual C++ 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Trying to set up libtins on windows. Im relatively new to Visual studio and most of the documentation on the matter was for older versions. I was able to get the include files set up with the project but linking the .lib's was problematic and i cant seem to configure it properly. The properties menu seems pretty convoluted as im used to doing most things compiler related configurations from a command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Solution Explorer, right click on the project, select Properties. Expand to Configuration Properties > Linker > Input. Add the .lib file to Additional Dependencies. Do this for both the Release and Debug configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If the static library in question is in fact the output of another visual studio project, you can just add that project to your solution file, and then add a reference to that project, and let VS2017 figure out where the lib files are located, and that the linker needs them.

i.e.

> - Solution '...' (2 projects)
>
>   - Lib Consuming Project
>
>     1. References(Lib Producing Project)
>   - Lib Producing Project

**hint for creating static libraries from visual studio**

for Lib Producing Project, go to Properties
*Properties->Configuration Properties->General*
and set *Configuration Type* to static lib (for both debug and release)

for foreign static libs, the accepted answer is AFAIK the proper way to do it.